# Reading emojis from an XML file using Python

Tags: python, xml, python-requests

I am trying to read emojis from [this](http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/annotations/en.xml) XML file. Copying them manually works, and they can be printed and still display correctly in the browser.

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(requests.get('http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/annotations/en.xml').text)

print(root[1][21].attrib['cp'])
```

This is supposed to fetch 'grinning face with smiling eyes' 
bytes(, 'utf-8') returns this: b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x84'.
But fetching using the code above produces 'ð\x9f\x98\x84'.
Is there something that should be done in the XML parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Response.text` will decode the content (see http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content).
`ElementTree` decodes the already decoded bytes again (based on `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`).

Try `Response.content` to pass the untouched response to `ElementTree`:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(requests.get('http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/annotations/en.xml').content)

print(root[1][21].attrib['cp'])
```